# Highlight the specific select2 passing the id selector to the function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I need to highlight only the #vans and not the #cars

Sometimes #vans can be multiple and sometimes it can be a non multiple too. However I must be able to specifically pass the ID selector to highlight the select. Here is the code below from [Highlight a select2 using highlight method and using css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074696/highlight-a-select2-using-highlight-method-and-using-css-selector) answer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  <select name="cars" class="mySelect" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Cars</option>
  </select>
  <select name="vans" class="mySelect" id="vans">
    <option value="volvo">Vans</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <script>
  function highlightSelect2(selector, isMultiple) {
  var isWhat = isMultiple ? '--multiple' : '__rendered'
  $('.select2-selection' + isWhat).effect("highlight", {
    color: '#f88'
  }, 10000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initilize select2
  $('.mySelect').select2();

  $('.mySelect').each(function(index, element) {
    let prop = $(element).prop('multiple')
    prop ? highlightSelect2("#vans",prop) : highlightSelect2("#vans")
  })
});
</script>
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that only the `select#vans` needs highlighting, you don't need to iterate over all Select2 jQuery items. Additionally, your `highlightSelect2` isn't using the `selector` you've passed in.

Using your code sample, I've modified it so that only the `#vans` element will be highlighted by:

- not iterating over all `select2` elements (using `.each`)

  - This lets you *only* highlight the `#vans`, directly
- Modifying `highlightSelect2` to use the passed-in `selector`
- Removing `isMultiple` logic — it wasn't necessary

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  <select name="cars" class="mySelect" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Cars</option>
  </select>
  <select name="vans" class="mySelect" id="vans">
    <option value="volvo">Vans</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <script>
  function highlightSelect2(selector) {

    $(selector)
      .next('.select2-container')
      .find(".select2-selection")
      .effect("highlight", {
        color: '#f88'
      }, 10000);
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initilize select2
  $('.mySelect').select2( { width: "25%" });

  // highlight the #vans select2
  highlightSelect2("#vans");
});
</script>
  
  
</body>
```

Run the code snippet and you'll see it works as you expect for your specific example.